# Determine if the following set is compact in the Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, compactness

> **Problem.** Consider the Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{N})$ formed by the sequences of complex numbers $x=\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n\overline{x_n} < \infty$ with the inner product $\langle x,y \rangle_{l^2(\mathbb{N})}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n\overline{y_n}$ where $y=\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.
>
> Find if the set
>
> $$\left\{x\in l^2(\mathbb{N}) : \langle x, x \rangle_{l^2(\mathbb{N})}=1, \  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n =0 \right\} $$
>
> is a compact set in the given space.

Don't know where to start as Heine Borel cannot be applied, any suggestions?

Comment: As a hint, check if the given set is sequentially compact. If you consider the set $$ F = \{ \mathbf{x} \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) : \langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} \rangle_{\ell^2(\mathbb{N})} = 1 \}, $$ you can choose the sequence of standard basis vectors $\mathbf{e}^{(n)} = \{\mathbf{1}_{\{ k = n\}}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, $n=1,2,\ldots$, that has no convergent subsequence. Can you adapt this example to your problem?

Comment: This set is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a look at the elements of the form $x^{(n)} = (0,0,\dots,0,1/\sqrt{2},-1/\sqrt{2},0,0,\dots)$, where the first $1/\sqrt{2}$ appears as the $n$-th entry. Can this sequence have any convergent subsequences?